# Referencing an internal variable in a JS object

Tags: javascript, singleton

In a simple JS object like this:

```
var LeadserData = {
    agent_id: 2,

    object_queries: {
        emails: {
            url: "/manual_emails/",
            method: 'GET',
              send_data: { 
                   the_id: this.agent_id
              }
        }
    }
}
```

it is obviously possible to access the agent_id simply like this:

```
LeadserData.agent_id = 100;
alert(LeadserData.agent_id);
```

This obviously returns 100. But why does not the internal reference of `this.agent_id` work?

```
alert((LeadserData.object_queries.emails.send_data.the_id));
```

I was expecting this to come out as "100" as well, but instead it is undefined.  The whole fiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/h88zc5nw/1/

What is the explanation for this behaviour, and how can I tweak this to return the expected `100`.

Comment: `LeadserData.agent_id` is not the same as `LeadserData.object_queries.emails.send_data.the_id`. Changing one will not affect the other as they are two different properties on two different objects.

Comment: The syntax does not return any errors, which expect it would do if this.agent_id was not valid.  Replacing it with f ex "RandomVariable" throws an error...

Comment: There's no error because there's no reason to error. The `this` value does reference an object (most likely) but just not the one you want.

Comment: ibrahim mahrir: So basically the reference, though referencing a dynamic variable, is static.  That makes sense, but is it a way of making it dependable?  The agent_id will be referenced a number of times in the code, and I would like to avoid updating every instance.

Comment: objects in javascript doesn't have scope, so in your code this refers to the Gobal scope, and for sure it undefined, checkout this, only functions ( first class objects in ja ) offer scopes so you need to wrap your code into a function .... it sounds like you're new to javascript :) [understanding-scope-in-javascript](https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-scope-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are using an object literal. You can't use `this` inside an object literal, at least it won't be what you think it is. It will be whatever `this` available while the object literal is constructed.

Second, even if we assume that the above works, numbers are native types, they won't be shared via their references. So changing `LeadserData.agent_id` won't affect `LeadserData.object_queries.emails.send_data.the_id` even if you have assigned one to the other. Native types are copied on assignment, not passed around using a reference (like you would do with an object).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  Now, as I understand ir "the_id" will then be "set" to the value of whatever it is referencing, but is there any way to make it dynamically dependend on any other value?  In the above example I would love to be able to declare agent_id only in one place (as the actual code will have a number of object_queries)

Comment: @charliez Why would you add that property to the `object_queries`? They all form the same object, just `LeadserData.agent_id` is sufficient, no?

Comment: No problem, you're welcome ...  checkout this, 
`(function() {
    var agent_id = 2,
        LeadserData = {


            object_queries: {
                emails: {
                    url: "/manual_emails/",
                    method: 'GET',
                    send_data: {
                        the_id: agent_id
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    console.log(LeadserData.object_queries.emails.send_data.the_id);
})();`

Comment: Problem is that agent_id need to be used in a number of AJAX calls and I was hoping to store the calls in one object.  There will be other content to each call, but agent_id will be part of many of them.  I just simplified the fiddle for clarity